# How to use data refresh in ajax grid as a trigger?

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In CF9 (ext js 3.1) I have a bound grid, populated by an ajax call, based on the value of a select box. The onChange event of the select triggers a js function. In this function, i'm trying to set a trigger on the grid refresh event, to execute some other code.
I've tried afterrender, reconfigure, load, nothing works: don't get an error, but function doesn't get triggered. 
If i change the event to something that happens AFTER the grid gets refreshed, like grid.addEvents('click') it works fine. What am I missing?

```
function myFunc(val) {
// ... some other code ...

  ColdFusion.Grid.refresh('myGrid',true);
  var grid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('myGrid');

  grid.addEvents('reconfigure'); 

  grid.on('reconfigure',function(){ 
    alert("Grid changed!");
  });           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ColdFusion.Grid.refresh('myGrid',true) starts executing asynchronously, the rest of the function keeps going and it can execute BEFORE the grid.refresh finishes.

I moved my triggered code to a different function and added a delay, not totally happy with it because the ajax call might be delayed too, for more than a second. If anybody has a better idea, i would appreciate to find out about it.

```
function myFunc(val) {
  // ... some other code ...

  ColdFusion.Grid.refresh('myGrid',true);

  myVar = setInterval(myOtherFunc,1000);
}

function myOtherFunc() {
  var grid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('myGrid');
  // add whatever code is needed
}
```